# Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ButtonProps': className, content

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button component

```
interface ButtonProps {
  className: string;
  content: string;
}

const Button = ({ className, content }): ButtonProps => {
  return <button className={className}>{content}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

My `App.tsx` imports it in the following context

```
import "./styles.scss";
import Button from "./button";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button className={"seeMore"} content={"See More"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My button component gives me the following error

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ButtonProps': className, content
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-7g4pe?file=/src/App.tsx:0-291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ButtonProps` wrong way. Just update like this:

```
const Button = ({ className, content }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <button className={className}>{content}</button>;
};
```